# Buttons to change cell reference in Excel

Tags: excel, list, button

I have a list of 500+ entries with customer data and we possibly want to change the ID number for the customers, and to make it easier to work with I wanted to create an interactive spreadsheet that display one customer at the time.

So in a new spreadsheet I want to display the customer from the first row, and then have a button that change the references in the cells to instead display the values from the second row, then the third row etc.

Please have a look at the attached pictures since I think they will explain the desired outcome better, and let me know if you don't understand what I mean.

Thank you in advance for your input!
BR,
Eric

**Customer list**

[image]

**Interactive part with buttons**

[image]

Comment: Use `Spin button` (has an up and down arrow) and "Cell Link:" it to a cell on that second sheet. Then you can use an `Index()` function to look up each value based on whatever row the `Spin Button` is set at.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment. From the Developer tab, choose "Insert" and pick the `Spin Button` from the list. Put it on your second sheet. Then right click the `Spin Button` you just added and go to `Format Control`. In `Cell Link` pick a cell on the second sheet (somewhere you can hide it). The you can use this value an in `Index()` formula to look up values from the other page.

As an example, I have three rows and two columns that I want to "Display row-by-row using a button". These are in `A1:B3`. I am displaying values in Column `E` using the formula shown in column `F`. Which are based on the value `2` which was chosen by hitting the up/down button on the `Spin Button`.

[image]

If I hit the "Up" button on the `Spin Button` that yellow cell changes automatically to `3` and the formulas adjust:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much JNevil!
I could never have imagined that there were such a neat and easy function availblie, worked like a charm :)